# Possible to add Ruby syntax highlighting to Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

When I open a Ruby file (*.rb) inside Visual Studio, it reads like a regular text file - with no syntax highlighting on language keywords.

Is there any way to set this up in Visual Studio?

Update: No, I don't use Visual Studio for Ruby development - I use Netbeans. But I would like to open a Ruby file in Visual Studio and see the proper highlighting.

Comment: One of the nice things about Visual Studio is that a cut and paste to Outlook keeps the syntax highlighted. Do any of the other Ruby editors you guys mentioned do that when pasted into a new Outlook message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Ruby plugin for Visual Studio by Sapphire Steel Software, called [Ruby in Steel](http://SapphireSteel.Com/).

Comment: there is a free edition - http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Ruby-In-Steel-New-Free-Edition

Comment: Is it compatible with VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a plugin in Visual Studio, that may do that.

Use Netbeans, Textmate, jEdit, Eclipse for Ruby development, they are great IDEs.

( I am wondering why are you doing ruby development in Visual Studio, well you may have your reasons :) )

Comment: I use Netbeans for Ruby development.

Comment: Not sure what the reason is for the original poster to use Ruby in VS2008, but I use Rake for my builds and to have Ruby highlighting to edit the rakefile.rb is a real bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you can do it for free without the Ruby in Steel add-in.

If you're not completely happy with Visual Studio, perhaps you can use a text editor with syntax highlighting plugins freely available. I know **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)** has this feature.