# Ruby syntax highlighting in visual studio 2012

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

I use `rake` scripts for running builds and would like to be able to get syntax highlighting within visual studio.

Is it possible to get ruby syntax highlighting in `Visual Studio 2012`?

I've been searching for a while but not come up with a solution yet.  I'm only looking for free solutions so [Ruby In Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/Ruby-In-Steel/article/ruby-in-steel-developer-overview) is out.

---

[Vote here](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/workitem/7345) for [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/) support for visual studio 2012

Comment: I am doing exactly that at the moment, but wouldn't it be nice not to have to change IDE and just be able to do everything in one?

Comment: I've used it before when doing ruby, nice IDE.  However we're writing an MVC4 app but rake and albacore really take the pain out of build configuration

Comment: It may well be but it's a faff I personally don't want of having to navigate to the file then open it in a different editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455406/possible-to-add-ruby-syntax-highlighting-to-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the [IronRuby tools for Visual Studio](http://ironruby.net/tools/) [don't yet support VS2012](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/workitem/7345).

I might be wrong about that though, it seems that the development [has been moved to Github](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main).

My preferred external editor is [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) so I've opted use that for Ruby files. You just right click on your rakefile.rb is the VS solution explorer and choose "Open With". In the dialog you can add an editor of your choice and set it to be the default.

Answer (score -1):

There was, at one point in 2008 anyway, a free edition of [Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Ruby-In-Steel-New-Free-Edition) and it seems like the download link on that page does still work. It has a slightly limited feature set compared to pay versions of the software, but does include syntax Highlighting. So have a go and see if that will do what you need for free.

And for the rest of you, Neil specifically asked for VS internal syntax highlighting, not for you to plug your favorite text editor.

Comment: Ruby in Steel doesn't seem to have a 2012 plugin version, have you managed to get this to work?